# How to create particle system by script

Tags: c#, unity, particles

I have created a gameObject called "Sphere". After 5 secs the gameobject starts rotating. Along with the rotation I need to emit partical from the object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your particle system to your gameObject. then you can activate it by something like this:

```
    // this is in the initial declaration
    particleEmitter pe;

    // this is in the Start() function
    pe = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().particleEmitter;

    // this go's inside your counter function and needs to get called 
    // when you activate to rotation
    pe.emit = true;
```

you need to turn of the emission component of the particle system in the editor